# InfluxDB goes down for huge data

Tags: influxdb

I am building a dashboard using InfluxDB. I have a source which generates approx. 2000 points per minute. Each point has 5 tags, 6 fields. There is only one measurement.

Everything works fine for about 24hrs but as the data size grows, I am not able to run any queries on influx. Like for example, right now I have approx 48hrs of data and even a basic select brings down the influx db,

```
select count(field1) from measurementname
```

It times out with the error:

```
ERR: Get http://localhost:8086/query?db=dbname&q=select+count%28field1%29+from+measuementname: EOF
```

### Configuration:

- InfluxDB version: 0.10.1 default configuration
- The OS Version:Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Configuration: 30GB RAM, 4 VCPUs, 150GB HDD

### Some Background:

I have a dashboard and a web app querying the influxdb. The webapp lets a user query the DB based on tag1 or tag2.

**Tags:**

- tag1 - unique for each record. Used in a where clause in the web app to get the record based on this field.
- tag2 - unique for each record. Used in a where clause in the web app to get the record based on this field.
- tag3 - used in group by. Think of it as departmentid tying a bunch of employees.
- tag4 - used in group by. Think of it as departmentid tying a bunch of employees.
- tag5 - used in group by. Values 0 or 1 or 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pasting answer from influxdb@googlegroups.com mailing list: https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/influxdb/b4fb503e-18a5-4bd5-84b1-632dc4950747%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

> tag1 - unique for each record.
>   tag2 - unique for each record.

This is a poor schema. You are creating a new series for every record, which puts a punishing load on the database. Each series must be indexed, and the entire index currently must reside in RAM. I suspect you are running out of memory after 48 hours because of series cardinality, and the query is just the last straw, not the actual cause of the low RAM situation.

It is very bad practice to  use a unique value in tags. You can still use fields in the WHERE clause, they just aren't as performant, and the damage to your system is much less than having a unique series for every point.

https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/concepts/schema_and_data_layout/
https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/guides/hardware_sizing/#when-do-i-need-more-ram

Comment: Absolutely. The following command can be very helpful if you want to investigate the results of your design: `/usr/bin/find /var/lib/influxdb/data -type f -name '*.tsm' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u | xargs --delimiter "\n" --max-args 1 --replace={} sh -c 'du -h {};echo "\n";influx_inspect report -detailed {};echo "\n"' > /var/log/influxdb/inspect_$(date +'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S').log 2>&1`

Comment: Further to the not-as-performant moving tag1 and tag2 to fields: if User Experience matters, check whether you can move the obvious queries users are likely to need into Continuous Queries. These will still be low-performing, but you'll move the performance hit into a time when people are likely not waiting.